# Position an image to a specific location

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I have a transparent image with a link which overlays a third party application on our portal. We cannot add html on the buttons so I thought this would be the solution. The image behaves as expected and positions itself correctly, however, when admins login to the portal and the admin menu appears it "pushes" the invisible image down for about 50 pixels so it causes confusion to the admins.

This is my code:

```
     <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="/Events.aspx">
            <img alt="Events" src="/Portals/1/transparent.png" 
              style="height: 43px; width: 200px; left: -150px; 
              position:absolute; z-index: 2000; top: 104px; right: 300px;  
              left: 500px;" /></a></td>
    </tr>
```

If I change the `absolute` to `relative` it causes other problems to the interface.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you explain it more? and what do you want?

Comment: Provide a screenshot of both instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `position: absolute` on the `<img>` makes the positioning properties refer to the first ancestor that isn't `position: static`. In this case I'm assuming it's the `<body>`. Try moving the reference point for the positioning closer to the image by adding `position: relative` to a closer ancestor and update the positioning properties. This will make your html more robust as additional content outside of the ancestor that got the `position: relative` won't influence the positioning of your image.

Unfortunately your example code is too incomplete to help you see possible candidates.

**updated based on the live example**

`.template_style` is currently the first ancestor with `position: relative` so all positioning properties refer to that. Try setting the `position: relative` on the module by doing (if that's possible and the module name isn't dynamic, otherwise an inline style attribute should work just as well)

```
.DnnModule-2190 {
  position: relative;
}
```

Afterwards update the `top` property (to `0`, `44px`, `88px` etc. I think) and `left` property (substract 7 I think).

Comment: I have added the live link to the page for more info

Comment: I believe it worked. Another problem that occurred is when a user is in 'edit' mode where another small box appears and re-pushes the links further down!

Comment: I'm guessing this should also fix that problem. Try if you can apply the same solution there.